# How is $\emptyset^* = \{\epsilon\}$?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I know that $\emptyset$ is a an empty language, i.e. language containing no string.

A law involving empty language is:

> $\emptyset L = L\emptyset = \emptyset$

It correctly states that we cannot concatenate non empty language $L$ with a language $\emptyset$ containing no string  (as their is no string to concatenate in $\emptyset$), it yields empty language.

Then how concatenating a language containing no string with itself any number of times can yield even empty string? That is, how following law exist:

> $\emptyset^* = \{\epsilon\}$

Comment: Has been asked before, I believe.

Comment: Was asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/908206/82433), and compare with an empty product

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any language $L$, by definition
$$ L^* = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty L^i, $$
where a word in $L^i$ is the concatenation of $i$ words from $L$. In particular, $L^0 = \{ \epsilon \}$ since $\epsilon$ is the concatenation of zero words from $L$. It doesn't matter if $L$ is empty or not, since we are choosing *zero* words from $L$.

Comment: but then concatenation of non-zero words in $L$ with zero words in $\emptyset$ yields $\emptyset$

Comment: Which is why all other powers of $L$ are empty.

Comment: So it really requires both languages to be empty to yield empty string. *If any one of them is non-empty, it will yield empty language*

Comment: No, $LM=\emptyset$ if either of $L,M$ is empty.

Comment: yes thats what I said above, I guess: *if any one of $LM$ is non empty, it will yield empty language*

Comment: btw did not get "*all other powers of $L$ are empty*", which *all other powers*

Comment: $\emptyset^n = \emptyset$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: I dont know whether I should discuss it further and just remember it as a standard definition. But still...to make myself feel comfortable I am making following analogy: *When you have to choose a string for concatenation ($L\emptyset$) from empty set, you cannot choose any and it results in empty set. When you don’t have to do concatenation itself ($L^0$) you get empty string.*

Answer (score 5):

$L^*$ can be defined as the smallest language satisfying the recursive equation

$$
L^* = \{\epsilon\} \cup L L^*
$$

or, equivalently as the the least fixed point of the (monotonic, Scott-continuous) language-valued function

$$
f(M) = \{\epsilon\} \cup L M
$$

over the complete lattice of languages (hence, by Tarski, such a fixed point exists).

The above definition may look quite abstract, but one can find it quite natural when comparing it to the usual definition of lists in functional languages as a recursive type:

```
data List l = Nil | Cons l (List l)
```

From the equation above, we can see that $ \epsilon \in L^* $ is trivially true whatever is $L$. (Not unlike the empty list being a list of `l`, whatever type `l` is.)